# Purpose of Would in these sentences

Tags: would

1. John said that he would be 15 by next year. 
   [ Past, Past]                 [Usage of would -  Indirect speech]
2. John says that he will be 15 by next year.
   [ Present, Future]      [Usage of will - will indicates future tense]
3. John says that he would  be 15 by next year.
   [ Present, Future]      [Usage of would – would indicates future tense ]

Is there any different between 2 and 3?

Does the first one conveys any different meaning than 2 or 3?

Comment: Sentence three is ungrammatical, in my view.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb: always make sure your tenses agree: the past with the past; the present with the present.

Thus, "said" should always go with "would," and "says" with "will."

Comment: No.  "Galileo maintained that the earth goes around the sun" (past, present).  "Tom says he would be happy to give you a ride if his car is running. (present, past)"

Comment: @Ever the apple polisher. Okay, the present (in Galileo's case) is used because that's what we believe <i>still</i>. To this day. As we speak. It's a frequently occurring exception. Your second example isn't in fact "present, past, present"; it's a subjunctive something or other, which is not predicated on ... uh ....chronology. I've got to memorize all those terms if only to spite you.

Comment: I'd suggest learning the difference between tense and temporality, but it's only a suggestion.

Comment: @deadrat: The former is characterized by strain; the latter is fleeting and/or transient. What's to learn. Don't talk in riddles: it scares some people.

Comment: *Tense* is a reference to a verb form; temporality is the time period referenced by the tense.  The past tense of *will* is *would*, but *would* doesn't always refer to past time.  Still scared?

Comment: @deadrat: Isn't that exactly what I said earlier? You're fantastically hard to please.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 1: Reported speech, with reporting verb in past tense. Therefore, '*will*' in reported clause becomes '*would*' (other modal verbs change in the same way too: e.g. *shall* -> *should*, *can* -> *could*, etc.)

Sentence 2: Reported speech, with reporting verb in the present tense used in direct speech. Fine.

Sentence 3: Ungrammatical as reported speech, because of the clash of tense/aspect between the two clauses, but capable of interpretation. You would have to interpret the modal in the subordinate clause as part of a conditional structure, with the *if*-clause implicit or suppressed: e.g. 'John says that he would be 15 next year, if only he hadn't been told he has only weeks to live.'